# Regex for up to but not including

Tags: regex

I have looked up the regex for up to but not including and found `(?:(?!x).)*` but it is not working for me and I am wondering what I am doing wrong.

```
/http:\/\/www.grasshopper3d.com\/forum\/topics\/.+(?!")/
```

The italics part in the URL below is the part I want but the regex tester at http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/ is telling me it's wrong. I don't understand.

href="*http://www.grasshopper3d.com/forum/topics/hoopsnake-iteration-component*"
_snid="2985220:Topic:24054

Comment: Which language are you embedding your regex in?  There are multiple sub-species or dialects of regex, and it may be that the language you're using doesn't support the dialect you are wanting to use.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, you could use a negated character class to pick up the material you want:

```
/http:\/\/www.grasshopper3d.com\/forum\/topics\/[^"]+/
```

This picks up any one or non-quotes after the `topics/`.

Your `.+(?!")` notation is doing negative lookahead, but the `.+` will eat up anything, including double quotes.  At the least, it makes the regex do extra work backtracking compared to the negated character class.  Lookahead has its place - especially when the lookahead is a multi-character word or the like.  I'm not convinced this is the place to use it.

Comment: Okay so for simple things I can just say "not including quotes". That seems to be working but I can't use that then for matching only the .gh files below by saying:
/http:\/\/www.grasshopper3d.com\/forum\/attachment\/download\?id=2985220%3AUploadedFile%3A[0-9]{6}[^.+\.gh]/      meaning "not including anything.gh"

It still includes the .jpg file.

"http://www.grasshopper3d.com/forum/attachment/download?id=2985220%3AUploadedFile%3A501843">01.jpg</a> 
"http://www.grasshopper3d.com/forum/attachment/download?id=2985220%3AUploadedFile%3A506981">SURFACE-DIAGRID-TEST.gh</a>

Comment: Yes; when you want 'not ending with `.gh`', then you need negative lookahead.